# Iterate over the two database datasets while comparing in python

Tags: database, python-2.7, loops, compare, iteration

Below mentioned code is used to compare two tables in same or different database. I am not able to retrieve the desired result to get unmatched records.

**My Problem:**
I am not able to print unique not matching records in table1 & table2 since I am finding difficulty in iterating row by row. Currently even matching records are printed as non matching records.

```
import psycopg2
conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='dvdrental' user='postgres' password='jai'"
db1 = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
db2= psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor1=db1.cursor()
cursor2=db2.cursor()
cursor1.execute("select * from public.actor order by 1")
results1 = cursor1.fetchall()
cursor2.execute("select * from public.actor order by 1")
results2 = cursor2.fetchall()
count1 =  len(results1)
count2 =  len(results2)
# print count1
# print count2
# print results1
# print results2
# print results1[0]
# print results2[0]
for i in range(0,count1):
    for j in range(0,count2):
        if (results1[i] == results2[j]):
            print "found"
        else:
            print "not found",results1
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just write your SQL query to handle this rather than iterating through them in python?

Comment: So feedback on your code not related to your exact question. There is no reason you should need to open 2 connections to the same database. You can use the same connection multiple times. Same goes for the cursor, though not as big of a deal as the connection. Connections add more overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried something like below code. Please let me know your feedback

```
import psycopg2
conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='dvdrental' user='postgres' password='jai'"
db1 = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
db2= psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor1=db1.cursor()
cursor2=db2.cursor()
cursor1.execute("select * from public.actor except select * from public.actor_1")
results1 = cursor1.fetchall()
cursor2.execute("select * from public.actor_1 except select * from public.actor")
results2 = cursor2.fetchall()
count1 =  len(results1)
count2 =  len(results2)
# print count1
# print count2
# print results1
# print results2
print results1
print results2
```

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to find matching values between two tables is to use join in SQL. However, I assume this is more of an exercise in Python than SQL.

You primary problem is that you have nested loops. Consider this illustration of what your loops are effectively doing:

```
list_a = ['a','b','c']
list_b = ['a','b','c']

for a_item in list_a:
   for b_item in list_b:
      print a_item,b_item
```

Output:

```
   a  a
   a  b
   a  c
   b  a
   b  b
   b  c
   c  a
   c  b
   c  c
```

If you expect the length of each iterable object to the the same and the elements to be in the same position, you would do something more like:

```
for index in range(0,len(list_a)):
   if list_a[index] == list_b[index]:
      print 'Found'
      continue
   print 'Not Found'
```

There are a few other changes you could/should make to your code, but they aren't immediately relevant to the problem you raised. Let me know if you'd like feedback on those.

### Using SQL

Disclaimer: You have not shared with me what columns each table has, but this should (hopefully) give you the concept:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

conn = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='dvdrental' user='postgres' password='jai'")

sql = """
SELECT
   a.Col1 AS Col1_a,
   b.Col1 AS Col1_b,
   CASE
      WHEN a.Col1 IS NOT NULL AND b.Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Match'
      ELSE 'No Match'
   END AS Result
FROM
   public.actor_1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN
   public.actor_2 b
   ON (b.Col1 = a.Col1);
"""

cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
cur.execute(sql)
results = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
conn.close()

for row in results:
   print row['Col1_a'], row['Col1_b'], row['result']
```

Comment: Oh great, Thanks you..It is working as expected. Please provide your feedback so that I can improve my code.

Comment: I am not getting exact results if Table2 contains one extra record (first record) .i.e. record which is not available in table1. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: @user6323298 - That is correct you won't, as I explained in my answer. What is your objective? For example, you have two different tables of data and you want to find the instances that exist in both? If so, writing SQL is going to be your best option. Let me know.

Comment: if SQL is the only best option to achieve result .i,e printing the differences between two tables. Please let me know how I need to implement in this code.Thank yiou

Comment: You still have not told me what your objective is. Are you trying to identify matches between the two tables or something different?

Comment: I am trying to identify only differences between two tables.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something like below code with extension. Please let me know your feedback

```
import psycopg2
import numpy as np
conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='dvdrental' user='postgres' password='jai'"
db1 = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
db2= psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor1=db1.cursor()
cursor2=db2.cursor()
cursor1.execute("select * from public.actor except select * from public.actor_1")
results1 = cursor1.fetchall()
cursor2.execute("select * from public.actor_1 except select * from public.actor")
results2 = cursor2.fetchall()
#count1 =  len(results1)
#count2 =  len(results2)
df1['results1']=df2['results2']
```

df1['not_match_matched']=np.where(df1['results1']==df2['results2'],'True','False')
    final=np.where(df1)[1]
    print(final)

## provide your feedback